# I have epilepsy can i work on cruise ships?

Tags: applications

I'm hoping to apply to work on cruise ships in the UK but I have to pass the ENG 1 medical first. I have epilepsy  haven't had a seizure in over a decade and am on medication for it but have no side affects from it. Will this limit me from either passing the ENG 1 or even getting q job on ships?

Answer (score 3):

**NB:** Either my memory deceived me or the rules have changed - updated post below!

The short version is that it depends on the nature of your seizures and time you've been without one, as well as what jobs you're going for.

Full info is in the [Approved Doctors Manual](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/901465/Approved_Doctors_Manual_July_2020.pdf) (specifically the ADG 7 section). But the gist is:

- **Single seizure** - Temporarily unfit category 3 until one year after the event AND one year after the end of any treatment. Then fit category 1.
- **Multiple seizures (unprovoked)** - Temporarily unfit category 3 until at least two years fit free and either off medication or on stable medication with good compliance. May then be considered restricted category 2 non-watchkeeping duties in UK near coastal waters on a case by case basis, depending on risks to self and others in the event of a further seizure and distance from medical care. Fit category 1 (including worldwide and watchkeeping) if without seizures and not on any anti epilepsy medication for last ten years, provided there is no continuing liability to seizures
- **Multiple seizures (provoked)** - Temporarily unit category 3 until at least one year of abstention from any known provoking factor (see MSN 1886, Standards 5.2 on alcohol), fit free and either off medication or on stable medication with good compliance. May then be considered restricted category 2 non-watchkeeping duties in UK near coastal waters on a case by case basis, depending on risks to self and others in the event of a further seizure and distance from medical care. Fit category 1 (including worldwide and watchkeeping) if without seizures and not on any anti epilepsy medication for last five years, provided there is no continuing liability to seizures from exposure to provoking substances.
- **Seizure risk from severe head injury, intracranial surgery, stroke or tumour** - Temporarily unfit category 3 for one year or more, based on advice from specialist, until such time as seizure risk is less than 5% p.a. Then restricted category 2 UK near coastal waters and no lone watchkeeping provided the underlying condition does not restrict employment until seizure risk less than 2% p.a. When less than 2% p.a. fit category 1

Basically if you're still on medication you're going to struggle to get cruise ship work thanks to the restriction to near coastal waters :(